# Slow elasticsearch query with french addresses with frequent words

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search

I migrate my project from solr to elastic due to company's policy

My requests with solr were fast but with elatic they are slow and my service can not handle the load I expect in requests per seconds because my system is cpu bound and requetst are too slow

My index contains all French street addresses :

- 25,462,993 entries
- 10GB index size

We have 3 primaries and 1 replica upon a cluster of 6 servers (32gb RAM / 8cpu)

We have applied all elastic.co's recommandations "tune-for-search-speed"

The java configuration is like this :

```
root@ELK001:~# ps aux | grep java
elastic+  45085  170 61.9 31052544 20460004 ?   SLsl 03:18 860:27 /bin/java -Xms16g -Xmx16g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-3573362637254362332 -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=rpm -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid
```

The slowest queries are those that use very frequent terms in out index like "1" or "rue" (street in french)
"rue" is present 13,287,097 times over 25,462,993 records

**An example of a slow query**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(querystring:/1.*/ )AND( querystring:/rue.*/ )AND( querystring:/du.*/ )AND( querystring:/parad.*/)",
            "fields": [],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "default_operator": "and",
            "max_determinized_states": 10000,
            "phrase_slop": 0,
            "escape": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "track_scores": true,
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["<em>"],
        "post_tags": ["</em>"],
        "require_field_match": false,
        "fields": {
            "ligne1": {},
            "ligne2": {},
            "ligne3": {},
            "numero": {},
            "ext_courte": {},
            "ext_longue": {},
            "libelle_voie": {},
            "libelle_voie_syn": {},
            "libelle_ligne_5": {},
            "libelle_acheminement_cedex": {},
            "libelle_acheminement": {},
            "code_postal": {},
            "code_cedex": {},
            "libelle_pays": {},
            "libelle_pays_syn": {}
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the profiler we see that the time is mainly spent on the most common keywords in the index : 1(number of the street) rue(street in french) du(of in french) and in the "build_scorer" phase

**Type  Self Time   Total Time  % Time**

BooleanQuery +querystring:/parad.*/ +querystring...   0.5ms   116.6ms **99.25%**

- MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper querystring:/1.*/   52.0ms  52.0ms  **44.25%**
- MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper querystring:/rue.*/ 38.1ms  38.1ms  **32.45%**
- MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper querystring:/du.*/  24.7ms  24.7ms  21.03%
- MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper querystring:/parad.*/   1.3ms   1.3ms   1.07%

**Timing Breakdown**

- build_scorer  24.6ms  **99.7%**
- advance   60.4µs  0.2%
- score 24.6µs  0.1%
- create_weight 110.0ns 0.0%
- match 0.0ns   0.0%
- next_doc  0.0ns   0.0%

**Index settings :**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "3",
      "provided_name": "s7_sint_profic_index2",
      "creation_date": "1619449230582",
      "requests": {
        "cache": {
          "enable": "false"
        }
      },
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "legacy_synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "bd => boulevard",
              "fg => faubourg",
              "saint,st",
              "sainte,ste",
              "I ,1,un",
              "II,2,deux",
              "III,3,trois",
              "IV,4,quatre",
              "V,5,cinq",
              "VI,6,six",
              "VII,7,sept",
              "VIII,8,huit",
              "IX,9,neuf",
              "X,10,dix",
              "XI,11,onze",
              "XII,12,douze",
              "XIII,13,treize",
              "XIV,14,quatorze",
              "XV,15,quinze",
              "XVI,16,seize",
              "XX,20,vingt"
            ]
          },
          "serca_stop": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": [
              "le",
              "la",
              "du",
              "de",
              "des",
              "au",
              "et",
              "l",
              "a",
              "d",
              "sous",
              "sur"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "filter": [
              "serca_stop",
              "lowercase",
              "legacy_synonym_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "uuid": "9KpNllG6TSi-AxLaB4ETyQ",
      "version": {
        "created": "6080099"
      }
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "index": {
      "max_inner_result_window": "100",
      "unassigned": {
        "node_left": {
          "delayed_timeout": "1m"
        }
      },
      "max_terms_count": "65536",
      "lifecycle": {
        "name": "",
        "rollover_alias": "",
        "indexing_complete": "false"
      },
      "routing_partition_size": "1",
      "max_docvalue_fields_search": "100",
      "merge": {
        "scheduler": {
          "max_thread_count": "4",
          "auto_throttle": "true",
          "max_merge_count": "9"
        },
        "policy": {
          "reclaim_deletes_weight": "2.0",
          "floor_segment": "2mb",
          "max_merge_at_once_explicit": "30",
          "max_merge_at_once": "10",
          "max_merged_segment": "5gb",
          "expunge_deletes_allowed": "10.0",
          "segments_per_tier": "10.0",
          "deletes_pct_allowed": "33.0"
        }
      },
      "max_refresh_listeners": "1000",
      "max_regex_length": "1000",
      "load_fixed_bitset_filters_eagerly": "true",
      "number_of_routing_shards": "5",
      "write": {
        "wait_for_active_shards": "1"
      },
      "mapping": {
        "coerce": "false",
        "nested_fields": {
          "limit": "50"
        },
        "depth": {
          "limit": "20"
        },
        "ignore_malformed": "false",
        "total_fields": {
          "limit": "1000"
        }
      },
      "source_only": "false",
      "soft_deletes": {
        "enabled": "false",
        "retention": {
          "operations": "0"
        },
        "retention_lease": {
          "period": "12h"
        }
      },
      "max_script_fields": "32",
      "query": {
        "default_field": [
          "*"
        ],
        "parse": {
          "allow_unmapped_fields": "true"
        }
      },
      "format": "0",
      "frozen": "false",
      "sort": {
        "missing": [],
        "mode": [],
        "field": [],
        "order": []
      },
      "priority": "1",
      "codec": "default",
      "max_rescore_window": "10000",
      "max_adjacency_matrix_filters": "100",
      "gc_deletes": "60s",
      "optimize_auto_generated_id": "true",
      "max_ngram_diff": "1",
      "translog": {
        "generation_threshold_size": "64mb",
        "flush_threshold_size": "512mb",
        "sync_interval": "5s",
        "retention": {
          "size": "512mb",
          "age": "12h"
        },
        "durability": "REQUEST"
      },
      "auto_expand_replicas": "false",
      "mapper": {
        "dynamic": "true"
      },
      "data_path": "",
      "highlight": {
        "max_analyzed_offset": "-1"
      },
      "routing": {
        "rebalance": {
          "enable": "all"
        },
        "allocation": {
          "enable": "all",
          "total_shards_per_node": "-1"
        }
      },
      "search": {
        "slowlog": {
          "level": "TRACE",
          "threshold": {
            "fetch": {
              "warn": "-1",
              "trace": "-1",
              "debug": "-1",
              "info": "-1"
            },
            "query": {
              "warn": "-1",
              "trace": "-1",
              "debug": "-1",
              "info": "-1"
            }
          }
        },
        "throttled": "false"
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "cache": "node"
      },
      "default_pipeline": "_none",
      "max_slices_per_scroll": "1024",
      "shard": {
        "check_on_startup": "false"
      },
      "xpack": {
        "watcher": {
          "template": {
            "version": ""
          }
        },
        "version": "",
        "ccr": {
          "following_index": "false"
        }
      },
      "percolator": {
        "map_unmapped_fields_as_text": "false",
        "map_unmapped_fields_as_string": "false"
      },
      "allocation": {
        "max_retries": "5"
      },
      "refresh_interval": "1s",
      "indexing": {
        "slowlog": {
          "reformat": "true",
          "threshold": {
            "index": {
              "warn": "-1",
              "trace": "-1",
              "debug": "-1",
              "info": "-1"
            }
          },
          "source": "1000",
          "level": "TRACE"
        }
      },
      "compound_format": "0.1",
      "blocks": {
        "metadata": "false",
        "read": "false",
        "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
        "read_only": "false",
        "write": "false"
      },
      "max_result_window": "10000",
      "store": {
        "stats_refresh_interval": "10s",
        "type": "",
        "fs": {
          "fs_lock": "native"
        },
        "preload": []
      },
      "queries": {
        "cache": {
          "enabled": "true"
        }
      },
      "ttl": {
        "disable_purge": "false"
      },
      "warmer": {
        "enabled": "true"
      },
      "max_shingle_diff": "3",
      "query_string": {
        "lenient": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index mapping :**

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "proficDocument": {
      "properties": {
        "cea": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "querystring": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "querystring_ligne4": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "querystring_ligne6": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "code_afnor": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "code_cedex": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "code_insee": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "code_insee_ancienne_commune": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "code_postal": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "commentaires": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "coordonnees": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "dateExport": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "dateRef": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "desc_voie": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "desc_voie_syn": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "ext_courte": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "ext_longue": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring",
            "querystring_ligne4"
          ]
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "_id"
        },
        "idza": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "libelle_acheminement": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring",
            "querystring_ligne6",
            "libelle_acheminement_str"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_acheminement_cedex": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_acheminement_str": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "libelle_commune": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_ligne_5": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_pays": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_pays_syn": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_projection": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "libelle_raison": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "libelle_voie": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring",
            "querystring_ligne4"
          ]
        },
        "libelle_voie_syn": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "ligne1": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "ligne2": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "ligne3": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring"
          ]
        },
        "matvoie": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "matvoie_syn": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "mention_speciale": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "mot_directeur": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "mot_directeur_syn": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "new_cea": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "numero": {
          "type": "integer",
          "copy_to": [
            "querystring",
            "querystring_ligne4",
            "numero_str"
          ]
        },
        "numero_mention_speciale": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "numero_str": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type_pays": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "type_projection": {
          "type": "integer",
          "index": false
        },
        "type_raison": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "type_synonyme": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "type_voie": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "type_voie_syn": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        },
        "x": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "y": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We are going to migrate elk from 6 elk 7 to try to solve this problem

**Do you have other suggestions?**

Comment: Can you define what "slow" means in your context? With only 10GB spread over 6 32GB data nodes, it should be a breeze to make it scream... I'll have a deeper look shortly, but the first thing I can say is that your queries look highly inefficient (`query_string` with regex is a big NO NO). Do you mind sharing the equivalent query you were previously running in Solr?

Comment: "slow" means that when we do a load test, it is cpu bound and requets are more and more "slow" and get over 3seconds 
The solr request was :
GET /solr/collection_profic/select?rows=30&start=0&q=querystring:((1* OR 1) AND (RUE* OR RUE) AND (DU* OR DU) AND (PARAD* OR PARAD))&hl=true&hl.fl=hl.ligne1&hl.fl=ligne2&hl.fl=ligne3&hl.fl=numero&hl.fl=ext_courte&hl.fl=ext_longue&hl.fl=libelle_voie&hl.fl=libelle_voie_syn&hl.fl=libelle_ligne_5&hl.fl=libelle_acheminement_cedex&hl.fl=libelle_acheminement&hl.fl=code_postal&hl.fl=code_cedex&hl.fl=libelle_pays&hl.fl=libelle_pays_syn&wt=javabin&version=2

Answer (score 0):

As Val already stated, your query looks inefficient.
Why not use a simple match query and check how it affects your performance?

```
GET yourindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "querystring": {
        "query": "1 rue du parad"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But there are two things that I'm not sure about.

1. Why do you use a seperate "querystring" field?
2. Why did you use the wildcards behind *1*, *rue*, *du* and *parad*?

Regarding 1., I'm not aware of your project, so no idea where your search data is coming from. But maybe it's even better to search on specific field(s) and combine the search with a bool query?

Comment: I would even venture into using [the `more_like_this` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) and see how it behaves.

Comment: `match` probably won't do because the search can be on substrings, i.e. `parad` should find `paradis`

Comment: As says @Val : match do not give same results

Comment: @Chules : the separate querystring contain all the content of all field (number in the street, street name, locality name and locality postal code)

Comment: @clood can you try a `more_like_this` query, just for the sake of it

Comment: @Val : i'm trying to make the more_like_this, i need some time to create it

Comment: @Val : the "more like this" do not give correct answers 
```
GET s7_sint_profic_index2/_search
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["querystring"],
            "like" : "1 rue du parad",
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @clood ok good to know. I've been working on a similar address search project (150M postal addresses all over US), so I'll share some ideas in a few